# how to release gpu after cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation: out of memory

Tags: cupy

after raise cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation: out of memory in fastapi, gpu is not freed, how to free gpu

```
  File "/app/app/core/color_retrieval.py", line 115, in _cal_distance
    dis = cp.subtract(mosaics, color) ** 2
          │  │        │        └ array([ 40., 161., 148.], dtype=float32)
          │  │        └ array([[[ 72., 156., 159.],
          │  │                  [108., 161., 163.],
          │  │                  [112., 153., 163.],
          │  │                  ...,
          │  │                  [196., 134., 132.],
          │  │          ...
          │  └ <ufunc 'cupy_subtract'>
          └ <module 'cupy' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/__init__.py'>

  File "cupy/_core/core.pyx", line 1248, in cupy._core.core.ndarray.__pow__
  File "cupy/_core/core.pyx", line 1575, in cupy._core.core.ndarray.__array_ufunc__
  File "cupy/_core/_kernel.pyx", line 1232, in cupy._core._kernel.ufunc.__call__
  File "cupy/_core/_kernel.pyx", line 611, in cupy._core._kernel._get_out_args
  File "cupy/_core/core.pyx", line 2647, in cupy._core.core._ndarray_init
  File "cupy/_core/core.pyx", line 188, in cupy._core.core.ndarray._init_fast
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 698, in cupy.cuda.memory.alloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 592, in cupy.cuda.memory._malloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 593, in cupy.cuda.memory._malloc
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 102, in cupy.cuda.memory.Memory.__init__
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/runtime.pyx", line 455, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.malloc
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/runtime.pyx", line 132, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.check_status

cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation: out of memory


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```